# Is there any Evernote version for Linux?

Tags: linux, note-taking

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and found that Evernote is a powerful note taking software.
But I can't find a Ubuntu (linux) version of this software.
Is there an Ubuntu client for Evernote? Or perhaps a similar program which works on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

There are several possibilities to chose from. If you want to stick with *Evernote* and its service, some clients are available to use. Andruseto [already mentioned Nevernote](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/17013/185), but there are also:

- *Everpad*. Available from one of Ubuntu's PPA repositories. Will sit in your system tray and stand-by to be used:
  [image: everpad]
  <sup>*Everpad* in the tray (click for larger variant)</sup>
  If you're using Unity, *Everpad* even offers its own lens.
- *Nixnote*. Hm, a dupe it might seem – AFAIK this was previously named "Nevernote", so it might overlap with Andresuto's answer. Never mind, here it is:
  [image: Nixnote]
  <sup>Nixnote (click image for larger variant)</sup>
  As you can see, this looks very much like the "official" Evernote on Windows ;) And again, it's available via PPA, see below.

Install hints:

```
# Everpad
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad

# Nixnote
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vincent-c/nevernote
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nixnote
```

Comment: @Andruseto As I wrote: *AFAIK this was previously named "Nevernote"* – so I assume so and pointed to your answer (I'm not using Evernote myself, and neither the mentioned clients, so I cannot tell for sure). And though it's a comment, and it seems we're sharing the same native language: Please remember this site uses English ;)

Answer (score 5):

There are other clients too such as

- Paperwork - [link](http://paperwork.rocks/)

[image: Paperwork]

- **Laverna** - [link](https://github.com/Laverna/laverna)
- **Everpad** - [link](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad) , already mentioned :p
- **Springseed** - [link](http://getspringseed.com/)
- **BasKet Note Pads** - [link](http://basket.kde.org/) , although originally for KDE but you have SVN repository access too

[image]

- **Keepnote** - [link](http://keepnote.org/)

[image]

IMO try Paperwork and Laverna , they are mature enough so you won't have to try anything else.

Comment: I need a feature that is not present in BasKet, I need ability to search inside all notes simultaneously.

Comment: A nice collection of links indeed. But if you check with our [guidelines for answers](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185), maybe you could add a little description to each? With that (maybe at least a short pro/cons for each), that would make a pretty useful answer. Thanks a lot!